# A random oracle as a CRHF

Tags: cryptography, hash-function, collision-detection

Reading through the book *Introduction to Modern Cryptography by Katz/Lindell*, I'm having some trouble understanding this part.
(It's on p.178 in 2e, chapter 5.5)
[image]

What I'm struggling with are:

1. How the assumption that A only outputs values previously queried does not harm generality?
2. Why is the probability that A succeeds is **upper-bounded** by the probability that $H(x_i)=H(x_j)$ for some distinct $i$ and $j$.

As they mentioned that is clear, I bet this would not require such long explanation, but as a newbie to cryptography, I'm confused.
Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is two addition of the book.

Comment: @kelalaka If you meant which edition, it is the 2nd. I added that to my question.